# Drupal View of CiviMember troubleshooting

Tags: views, civicrm

I've created a Drupal View of our current members in CiviMember

```
SELECT civicrm_contact.organization_name AS civicrm_contact_organization_name,    civicrm_website.url AS civicrm_website_url
FROM 
{civicrm_membership} civicrm_membership
LEFT JOIN {civicrm_contact} civicrm_contact ON civicrm_membership.contact_id =  civicrm_contact.id
LEFT JOIN {civicrm_website} civicrm_website ON civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_website.contact_id
WHERE (( (civicrm_membership.status_id IN  ('4', '5', '6')) AND   (civicrm_contact.contact_type NOT IN  ('Individual', 'Household')) ))
ORDER BY civicrm_contact_organization_name ASC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

But it keeps on returning duplicate results, sometimes 3 or 4 in a row and yet they're all single contact records with one current membership? Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there nothing to give you a clue in the actual table of results? Eg are the duplicates ones that have multiple websites (since that field has not filtering in field for ' website type' afaik but you should be able to apply a Views Filter)
That seems the most likely reason.
If not, have you tried setting the Query Settings (under Advanced) to Disinct or Pure Distinct.
If none of that helps, can you attach the view?

Comment: No clue no, but adding Distinct remove 95% of the duplicates, so that's very helpful

Comment: do you want to 'export' the View and paste?

Comment: is that not what I did above?

Comment: no - you pasted the query. i meant export the whole view, then i can easily recreate on my site and test

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Zw2CXjv6

Apologies for the delay

Comment: okay - no guaranteed answer but ... So this is a view build on Memberships rather than Contacts. Hence you will get a row for every membership a contact has. Do any of your duplicates have multiple membership records?

Comment: it may be easier to check if you add Display Name have that link back to their civi record to make it. Org Name field is "The display name of the contact's organizations." which in theory is the individuals employer but maybe it now also works the same as Display Name if the contact is an Org.

Comment: Finally - it may be that you need to switch this view to be working off CiviContacts rather than CiviMemberships.

Comment: oh - so was this an issue related to Website URL for contacts that had multiple values of that field?